# Next printf comes before my scanf takes input

Tags: c, while-loop, switch-statement, printf, scanf

I am creating a calculator file in C with a `while` loop and a `switch` statement. The first time through the `while` loop, everything works fine, but when it goes through the second time, the my `printf` gets called before I have the opportunity to enter the data into the preceding `scanf`.

I have tried using `'\n'` before the text in the `printf` and I have also tried using `fflush(stdout)` before and after the `scanf` call.

**Current output:**

```
Welcome to the Calculator  
Operation choices:  Addition(A)
                    Subtraction(S)
                    Multiplication(M)
                    Division(D).  
Enter choice: A  
Enter both numbers in required sequence: 50 50  
// the output of the calculator does <>= 100 // Equal to 100.   
Welcome to the Calculator  
Operation choices:  Addition(A)
                    Subtraction(S)
                    Multiplication(M)
                    Division(D).  
Enter choice: Enter both numbers in required sequence:
```

**What I want:**

```
Welcome to the Calculator  
Operation choices:  Addition(A)
            Subtraction(S)
            Multiplication(M)
            Division(D).  

Enter choice: A 

Enter both numbers in required sequence: 50 50  
// the output of the calculator does <>= 100 // Equal to 100.   
Welcome to the Calculator  
Operation choices:  Addition(A)
            Subtraction(S)
            Multiplication(M)
            Division(D).  
Enter choice: // then I can enter a new choice for the switch //
```

**The code I've tried:**

```
while(input != 'q'){
    printf("Welcome to the Calculator\nOperation choices:\tAddition(A)\n\t\t\tSubtraction(S)\n\t\t\tMultiplication(M)\n\t\t\tDivision(D)\nEnter choice: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%c", &input);
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("\nEnter both numbers in required sequence: ");
    scanf("%f %f", &num1, &num2);

    switch(input){
    case 'A':
      result = num1 + num2;
      break;
    case 'S':
      result = num1 - num2;
      break;
    case 'M':
      result = num1 * num2;
      break;
    case 'D':
      result = num1 / num2;
      break;
    default:
      printf("Please choose a valid operation.");
      break;
    }

    if(result > 100){
      printf("Greater than 100.\n");
    }
    else if(result < 100) {
      printf("Less than 100.\n");
    }
    else{
      printf("Equal to 100.\n");
    }
  }
  printf("Quit the menu.\n");
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: It is not safe to use the output of `scanf` without first checking the return value of `scanf`. See this link for further information: [A beginner's guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Comment: `scanf("%c", &input);` --> `scanf(" %c", &input);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this : `scanf(" %c", &input);` (add space before `%c`)

`scanf` will likely take `\n` in buffer as input and placed in you character `input`.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of events in you program is correct, what happens is that `scanf()` reads a lingering `'\n'` new line character that is left in the `stdin` buffer from a previous input. The `'\n'` is consumed by `scanf()` and the program continues the execution.

You will need to clear the buffer before `scanf()` is executed.

**Option 1** - Clear the buffer at the bottom of the `while` cycle:

```
//...
int c;
//...
else{
  printf("Equal to 100.\n");
}
while((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF){}
//...
```

**Option 2** (simpler) - Use a space before `%c` specifier:

```
scanf(" %c", &input);
       ^
```